# Accessing changed files for a pull request in pre build script before executing GitHub actions

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, github-api, pre-build-event

I am trying to do user authentication if a pull request contain changes in certain folders. I am intending to do this even before GitHub actions are triggered using [pre-build script](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/running-scripts-before-or-after-a-job). I am able to access the user information using the environment variable `github_event_path` and extract author using jq.

Now I am not able to find a way to get changed files(thus finding out what folder a change is made, based on the absolute path) in this pre-build shell script. I tried using `${{steps.files.outputs.all}}` that is used in getting the changed files in GitHub actions. I think `steps` is not accessible in pre-build shell scripts as I got *bad substitution* error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.